# When do changes to a QML file not take effect?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qmake

I've had a problem happen for the second time over the last week. It seems to happen randomly. I change something in a QML file, save it, run the app, and see that my change has not taken effect. I rerun the app and it still has not taken effect.

The first time this happened to me, it got fixed by itself after I did some git stuff (in this order: `git stash save`, rollback to an older revision, go back to the newest revision, `git stash pop`). The second time I didn't do that, but ran qmake from the Qt Creator menu and that fixed it.

**What could be the cause of the problem?**

I'm using Qt Creator 4.1.0.

Comment: Qt has had that problem for as long as I have used it, that's almost 7 years now, even before QML you had to occasionally clean and rebuild all just to get changes reflected. Wonder how many more years it will take to fix it...

Comment: Are you loading the QML files from a resource? If so have you rebuilt?
In general I would just use direct file access during development, as this allows even reloads while the application is running

Comment: @KevinKrammer: Loading from a resource, yes. The "Run" command normally rebuilds my project automatically when there are changes, so I have not rebuilt manually, instead assuming that Creator will do it for me.

Comment: It usually does, or rather the build system in question does, e.g. make/nmake/jom/ninja. Are the QML files listed in the resource file or is it using some kind of file pattern?

Comment: @KevinKrammer: The qrc file lists all my QML files currently. I don't know if that was true at the moment when the problem occurred, though.

Comment: I have only ever run in this problem when files were not individually known to the build system.
In any case I would recommend to load the main file (and thus all related ones) from files during those stages of development where you change the QML content. Way faster not to have to rebuild, even reload without restart possible, etc

Answer (score 3):

Stephan i have seen this happening and from what i have read before is a know bug, more information can be found in:

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-1627

The thing is that it seems qtcreator is unable to detect a change of qlm/qrc files being changed, so the makefiles are not being updated due qmake is not being run.

seems they are not going to be solved bug, it has been already for years there, the workaround in qtcreator is to  run qmake manually and after rebuild.

Comment: For qml file changes only running qmake alone seem to suffice. I suspect it is the same type of bug which requires to clean and rebuild all of the c++ code every once in a while.

Comment: I agree but is very annoying the fact of this happening as if its not predictable for UI development is a problem. So i am going to try to compile a list of the cases its happen and will share back :), so even if its manually we can kind of know all the cases qmake needs to be run :)

Comment: qmake usually doesn't need to run unless something in the project setup changed. Depending on the build system, e.g. make, the generated files should have all the necessary update rules and the build tool should detect the changes and the required build chains to run. So this depends a bit on which tool is being used for building and how it detects change

Comment: I agree @KevinKrammer, and for sure we need to say that this is actually a QtCreator bug (that is the main development tool for qt apps) and not general Qt. 
Qtcreator defines normally 2 steps on the build run qmake and make, the issue is that both are not always run, normally make is the only one being run unless you do changes to the .pro (that will cause a run of the qmake step). The thing is QtCreator (from what i have experience) tends to fail to detect some modifications on the qrc that should also require qmake to run (I need to investigate and try more to pinpoint the specific cases).

Comment: No, QtCreator shouldn't need have to re-run qmake manually, the generated makfile should have rules to do that. Just like it does for changes of the .pro file. After all is one of the main jobs of a build tool such as make to know which commands to run again.
If there is a problem it is more likely in qmake not generating the correct make rules.

Comment: But is the responsability of qmake to generate a valid makefile. runing qmake will change the makefile, If there is an extra-dependency being required to build correctly the changes to the qrc file. And all that is working correctly as it should.
The issue itself is Qt creator not running qmake as it should to modify the makefiles in specific cases of modifications on the qrc file. If you add some dependencies that need to be propagated to the makefile it makes sense that QtCreator should catch them all and decide to run qmake no?

Answer (score 2):

I just hit this problem again, this time despite diligently running qmake before every run.

I think I figured out what caused it this time. It's that I was using the small Run button (actually called "Re-run this run configuration") that resides in the "Application output" pane's toolbar. Seems like this button has the treacherous property of running **without rebuilding**.

The solution is to use Ctrl+R, or, equivalently, the big run button in the vertical toolbar along the left side of the window.

---

Another time the problem wouldn't go away until I deleted the `myproject.pro.user` file.